# Select same column from multiple tables with condition and LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql

I have two tables with fiew similar columns :

One is for `SellOrders`

```
OrderID (PK)| id_seller| id_product| placement_date
```

And the other is for `BuyOrders`

```
OrderID (PK)| id_buyer| id_product| placement_date
```

With another table `Customer` concerning customers informations (Buyers and sellers)

```
id_customer(PK) | name_customer
```

And a `Product` table :

```
id(PK) | name_product
```

I want to write an SQL statement that will select the first `placement_date` when the a buy order or sell order was placed for the product and the correspending `name_customer` + `the name_product`.

I wrote a query that select the same logic but for only the selling side and I am looking to select the data for both buy and sell side :

```
SELECT p.name_product, s.placement_date, c.name_customer
FROM Product p
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 placement_date, id_seller
             FROM Selling
             WHERE id_product = p.id
             ORDER BY placement_date, OrderID ASC) s
LEFT JOIN Customer c 
ON c.id_customer = s.id_seller
```

From what I have seen `UNION SELECT` seems to be the way to do this. I added `UNION` to the `OUTER APPLY`:

```
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 placement_date, id_seller
             FROM Selling
             UNION 
             SELECT TOP 1 placement_date, id_buyer
             WHERE id_product = p.id
             ORDER BY placement_date, OrderID ASC) s
```

But I get stuck at the `LEFT JOIN` with the table `Customer`.
Any help ?

Comment: Please add sample datas and expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've got it right you want first of union of buy/sell orders

```
SELECT p.name_product, s.placement_date, c.name_customer
FROM Product p
OUTER APPLY (
     SELECT TOP 1 placement_date, id_cust
     FROM ( 
        SELECT placement_date, OrderID, id_seller id_cust
        FROM SellOrders 
        WHERE id_product = p.id
        UNION 
        SELECT placement_date, OrderID, id_buyer
        FROM BuyOrders
        WHERE id_product = p.id
        ) t
      ORDER BY placement_date, OrderID ASC
   ) s
LEFT JOIN Customer c 
ON c.id_customer = s.id_cust
```

Comment: thank you for your help. The customer might be the first seller or buyer that placed the order. Why are you still joining on the seller only ?

Comment: @IMEmma, quite contrary. `id_cust` is the name  of joined buyers and sellers . The upper select of the UNION gives the names to the derived table columns.